# Plsql dynamic sql statement

Tags: sql, plsql, procedure

I am executing these 2 statements in a procedure.

```
 execute immediate 'create table temp_test(user_state varchar(100), user_goal varchar(100))';
      insert into temp_test values('sunil','test');
```

and it is giving me error **table not found.**

so i just want to know that dynamic sql statement will not execute statement immediately.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do the insert also dynamic:

```
begin
  execute immediate 'create table temp_test(user_state varchar(100), user_goal varchar(100))'; 
  execute immediate 'insert into temp_test values('sunil','test');';
  COMMIT ;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! How can we insert variable in execute immediate statement? sorry i am new for procedure writing:)

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
begin
  execute immediate 'create table temp_test(user_state varchar(100), user_goal varchar(100))'; 
  execute immediate 'insert into temp_test values(''sunil'',''test'')';
  COMMIT ;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! How can we insert variable in execute immediate statement? sorry i am new for procedure writing:)

Comment: You can use USING clause. Check Example 7.1      in the link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, that dynamic sql statement will not execute statement immediately. Check this answer [execute immediate create table and update table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702495/execute-immediate-create-table-and-update-table/5702559#5702559)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! How can we insert variable in execute immediate statement? sorry i am new for procedure writing:)